# Ubuntu: remap single key to keys combination

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

Is it a way in ubuntu linux to remap single key (for example, Alt_R) to keys combination (for example, Up)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you want to examine is xmodmap.  You can modify your keys as you wish; if you add the key settings to a file in your home directory (like .xmodmaprc) it will take effect on login as long as you run xmodmap with that file.  You can also set the settings on the fly.  Using the man (or xman) command will show you more information.

There are also graphical interfaces that do the same thing for both GNOME and KDE, though I don't know what they are.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at xmodmap then at the [following guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultimediaKeys) on how to enable it on login

Answer (score 0):

I've found that `xev` is a useful program to get key codes when making rules for `xmodmap`.

Also, note that Alt_R is a modifer key; you will have to use the "remove" command to make it a non-modifier key before you can use a "keycode" or "keysym" command on it.